Convert Python to exe for Windows XP SP 3
I want to create a Django project and convert it to an exe file for Windows XP SP3, but I can't pip install the versions that works for Windows XP SP3
i tried searching many websites and always got this:
Collecting Pyinstaller
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pyinstaller (from versions: ).
No matching distribution found for Pyinstaller.



There’s a project called Django2Exe that aims to help distribute Django projects as .exe files.
It uses WinPython and Cefpython3 to package your Django project.
You can follow the instructions in the GitHub repository to set it up.

python --version? pip --version?

You realize that WindowsXP has been obsolete for a very long time now?  Good luck!

windows XP? maybe if you find something which packs a Linux VM as a binary blob with an .exe wrapper. Otherwise, that is not feasible for modern Python.
